# Angular: Obtain data from different steps of a wizard

Tags: angular, events, components, wizard

Imagine that we have a Wizard of 3 steps.

I would like to know if there is any solution to get the data filled from the Step1  and Step2 to Show them into a Step3.

Each Step is a diffrent component. I know that Step3 would have to get two inputs. My question is, how to send the data to the Step3 component on the Step1 and Step2?

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a shared service from your different components.

Comment: Yeah, something like this was what I was thinking about, but would like to see some other solution if exists! Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is an easier way to do this. Component interaction can be summarized to shared service, input binding (in your case I don't think you can implement this) and ViewChild binding which would be harder to implement than a simple service.

Answer (score 0):

Using a shared service, you can easily achieve this.

Don't forget to set properly the provider of the said service.

wizard.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class WizardService{

  constructor() { }

  public void setStep1(){ /*do something*/ }
  public void setStep2(){ /*do something*/ }
  public void setStep3(){ /*do something*/ }

}
```

step1.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { WizardService} from './wizard.service.ts';

@Component({
  ...
})

export class Step1Component

  constructor(private wizardService: WizarService) { }

  onClick(){
    this.wizarService.setStep1();
  }
}
```